# Merging DEM file generted many negative value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, raster, dem

With four DEM files downloaded by Python Elevation package, I merged them in QGIS 2.8.3.

I use `raster-> Miscellanaous -> Input direction`, no more attribute was added.
[image]

The four dem data has the elevation range roughly from (-100,2000) meters.

But in the merged file, the data range was from -30000 to 2000 meters.

The data distribution are shown here:

[image]

Comment: Your files are in Geotiff format, dou you know what is the null value for your files? This can vary depending on the format....

Comment: Did you check the validity of the individual DEM layers? perhaps one of them corrupted? As @GerardoJimenez says, the negative values look suspiciously like a signed 16 bit minimum value of -32768

Comment: I'll recheck my data